# Edit war over is-it-a-duplicate - trailing comma

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220074/how-does-initializing-an-integer-as-a-1-compile) about the meaning of a trailing comma was posted today.  I closed it as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason).

Another poster re-opened it , asserting that since the term "exact duplicate" is an oxymoron and I had admitted it was not an "exact duplicate" then it should be open.

However I (and another poster) feel the issue the question is asking about is superbly answered by the suggested duplicate which provides a lot of additional rationale (unlike the bare-bones answer which the warrior has approved after re-opening).

I don't think we should have 3 separate questions for each of these pieces of code:

```
int a = { 1, };
int a[1] = { 1, };
struct S s = { 1, };
```

As a comparable example, there are dozens of questions asking variations on "what does `i = i++;` do?" which all get closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) despite the questions have different variables names, and different expressions.

Comment: Seems borderline to me. You could certainly argue that a question about the syntax for initializing a scalar is different from one about initializing an array.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm kinda bad with this website, but I'm going to give a shot at defending one of the posters on there. The C++11 standard says in [dcl.init] p13 that

> The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally
>   insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity
>   being initialized has a class type; see below. If the entity being
>   initialized does not have class type, the expression-list in a
>   parenthesized initializer shall be a single expression.

Yet would you argue that all questions about initialization should be closed as duplicates of each other? I see lots of questions on the website about different forms of initialization, where even though the syntax is very similar, the questions and answers are very different.

I also don't agree with your example:

```
int a = { 1, };
int a[1] = { 1, };
struct S s = { 1, };
```

The last one only has similar semantics because there's only one element in the initializer, but change it up and it becomes a very different scenario. I would argue the same thing for my question. A scalar initializer has different semantics than initializing an array even though the same rules apply.

Comment: This is just about whether or not brace-enclosed initializers can have a trailing comma. And you could say about *any* scenario, "change it up a bit and it becomes a very different scenario".

Comment: Note that *expression-list* in your quote refers to the part of the list excluding the trailing comma (see [syntax]/2)